# Если input пуст, то в нем писать 0, JS

Tags: javascript, html, input

Начал изучать JS, столкнулся с такой проблемой

```js
 function result(){
 var zerc = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT").value;
 if (zerc == ''){
  zerc == '0';
 }
}
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = result(); // Ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Zero</title>
 <script src="js/zerocount.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="number">
  <br><br>
 <input type="number">
  <br><br>
 <input type="number">
  <br><br>
 <input type="number">
  <br><br>
 <input type="number">
  <br><br>
 <input type="number">
  <br><br>
 <input type="number">
  <br><br>
 <input type="number">
  <br><br>

  <input id="btn" type="button" value="0" onclick="result()">
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Во-первых, у массива элементов не бывает никакого value. Во-вторых, судя по всему, ваш скрипт выполняется ещё до того, как btn появляется в html-коде

Comment: В-третьих, вы зачем-то пихаете в onclick не функцию, а результат вызова функции, то есть undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function result(){
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].value == ''){
      input[i].value = '0';
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = result;
```

А вообще стоит использовать placeholder для таких случаев.

Comment: Спасибо за исправление, скопипастил и не заметил ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно html-элементу задать аттрибут `placeholder` с нужным значением

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Zero</title>
 <script src="js/zerocount.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="number" placeholder="0">
  <br><br>

  <input id="btn" type="button" value="0" onclick="result()">
 
</body>
</html>
```